# Why CALL command cannot execute a command enclosed with brackets?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The behavior is the same both in the command prompt and in a .bat file.

```
@echo off

:: the echo that will never be
call(echo echo echo)

:: its the same with non-cmd internal commands
call ( notepad.exe )

:: and even with a code that should fail
call(gibberish)

:: moreover the execution is successful
call (gibberish)&&echo %errorlevel%

:: though there's some parsing done
call(this will print call help because contains "/?"-/?)

:: and will detect a wrong syntax of some parsed-before-execution commands
call ( if a==)

:: and this too
call (%~)

:: same with labels
call(:label)
call(:no_label)
:label
```

[According to the microsoft documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true):

`Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols  - (command1 & command2) Use to group or nest multiple commands.`

[Here's the **CALL** help page.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx) - So nothing that indicates that syntax is illegal as long as redirection symbols are not used.

More bugs in CALL parser - [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5547&p=35450#p35450)

Comment: Probably because that's not part of the specification for the CALL statement.

Comment: Because it's invalid syntax for CALL.

Comment: @KenWhite How the syntax is invalid? - here's the call help page and nothing is mentioned about brackets : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx

Comment: Because the CALL help page says nothing about brackets being allowed?

Comment: The only place I've found in microsoft documentation about brackets is here : http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true   - ( )[...](command1 & command2) - Use to group or nest multiple commands.

Comment: @KenWhite Here's something form help pages:  `Call has no effect at the command-line when used outside of a script or batch file.` which is obviously wrong.

Comment: There are very few specifications about cmd.exe and then they are not very exact or simply wrong

Comment: does it matter that the call and the open bracket are connected `call(`, possible syntax error?  Possible change to `call (`

Comment: @Alex - In fact `call(` does not give a syntax error :-) . The result of the code in the question will be the same with `call ( command )` . But was a good remark.

Answer (score 2):

Enter in command prompt window `cmd.exe /?` and view the last paragraph on last displayed page which belongs to file completion:

```
The special characters that require quotes are:  
     <space>  
     &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
```

So all strings with one of those special characters must be enclosed in double quotes.

As file completion is done by `cmd.exe`, it can be expected that parsing of a line is done similar for entire command lines as well as for lines in batch files.

It is possible to use for example

```
call "( Notepad.exe )"
```

which of course results in an error message as Windows will not find an executable with name `( Notepad.exe )` to call.

I have learned just an hour ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434965/task-scheduler-status-still-shows-as-running-after-a-bat-completes-its-task/24436727#24436727) from an interesting comment by [phd443322](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3724689/phd443322) that cmd.exe parses lines different than all other applications.

As this question will be read most likely never by a programmer with access to source code of `cmd.exe`, we will never get the answer why those example commands are interpreted as we can see on executing them.

Comment: the cited excerpt from the `cmd` in fact concerns file completion and is discussed here : http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5493  . This is rather bug in `CALL`  parser  - here are more cases when CALL behaves indecently - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5547&p=35450#p35450

Comment: Entering `cmd.exe` in command prompt window simply invokes another CMD session. Did you mean `cmd.exe /?`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only commands that interpret parenthesis as delimiters for an expression are FOR, IF and SET /A

Adding new lines may look promising:

```
Call (
 Echo Hello
)
```

but if you try running just

```
Call (
```

what that is actually doing is attempting to run the command `(.cmd`
If you try creating a batch file called `(.cmd`, then you can in fact call it with

```
Call "("
```

The quotes are required because `(` is a 'special' character.

In PowerShell parenthesis can be used in many more places which can be confusing if you switch between CMD and PowerShell

```
(2+3)
```

Will return 5 in PowerShell but just gives an error in CMD.

Comment: left alone brackets are also expression delimiters and even can unite the pipes/conditional execution -> `(echo a & echo b )|more` . I think the `CALL` recognize them as an expression delimiters but is just buggy.