# Task Scheduler status still shows as Running after a BAT completes its task

Tags: batch-file, task, taskmanager

I'm attempting to create a batch file that I can use with Task Manager in Windows 7 to copy users' local Google Earth file to a network location where it can be backed-up.  It appears that the BAT is running just fine, but the task does not complete or stop once it's done & continues to show a status of "running".

Thanks in advanced for the suggestions!

```
COPY/Y "C:\Users\lena.domain\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth\myplaces.kml" "\\server\u-users\Lena\system backup\Google Earth"  cmd.exe /C
```

Comment: Did you call the batch file `copy.bat` ?  Try a different name, if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your single line in a command prompt window results in error message: `syntax error`

Reason 1: There is no space between command `COPY` and option `/Y`.

Reason 2: There is `cmd.exe /C` appended at end of the line.

Use in your batch file the line:

```
COPY /Y "C:\Users\lena.domain\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth\myplaces.kml" "\\server\u-users\Lena\system backup\Google Earth"
```

And additionally make sure that this job is executed from task scheduler with credentials (account) which has the permission to write something on server. The local SYSTEM account often used for scheduled tasks has surely no permissions to access files on the server at all. It looks like the best account to use for this scheduled task is the user account of `lena.domain`. See also [Configure a Scheduled Task Item (At least Windows 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851678.aspx)

Comment: Reason 1 is not an issue. Cmd doesn't require a space, it requires a delimiter, which both space and the switch character are.

Comment: Also if cmd is parsing the commandline, as in internal commands, then it applies to whole cmd line eg `dir/a/s/d`. To my knowledge cmd is only program in windows that doesn't require spaces.

Comment: [phd443322](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3724689/phd443322), you are right. The missing space between `COPY` and `/Y` does not produce the syntax error message. So only `cmd.exe /C` is responsible for the error message. However, there should be a space between an internal command and the options respectively parameters for the command as it is necessary for all other applications except cmd.exe.

Comment: Just a quirk of cmd that I love. It saves 1 (sometimes 2) keystrokes per dir cmd. I feel the need to share it.